# Getting attribute from arff file after training process

Tags: java, weka

I have arff file that its name project.arff
It contains attributes, they are "location, price and area" and contain many of data 
and i have code in java that linked with weka...
And I have a customer which will enter the price and the area in a java code and then I will give him the suitable location "one location only" from arff file
How can I get an only one data "location" after training process?
This is my code:

```
BufferedReader breader = null;
breader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/User/Desktop/projectt.arff"));
Instances train = new Instances(breader);
breader.close();
NaiveBayes nb=new NaiveBayes();
nb.buildClassifier(train);
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
eval.crossValidateModel(nb, train, 10, new Random(1));
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", true));
System.out.println(eval.fMeasure(1) + " "+ eval.precision(1)+ " " + eval.recall(1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Instances method `attribute(int index)` to retrieve a particular feature like location as you specified.And you can also call value by attribute name also.

```
Attribute att=train.attribute("location");
```

Comment: sorry
I would like to get the attribute's value from a resultant cluster not all attribute's values

Comment: Means you want to get attribute from an instance????Actually using Attribute class associated with only an instance.